# Solving an initial value problem involving the second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation $y''(x) = y(x) \cdot y'(x) + (y'(x))^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have the following equation $y''(x) = y(x) \cdot y'(x) + (y'(x))^2$ with the initial values $y(1) = 0$ and $y'(1) = -1$.

I am seeking some guidance for how to best tackle this particular problem.

[this](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html) article suggests that a v substitution may reduce the problem in some capacity. Thus I let $v = y'(x)$ as follows:

\begin{align*} 
y''(x) &= y(x) \cdot y'(x) + (y'(x))^2 & (1) \\
y''(x) &= y(x) \cdot v + v^2 & (2) \\
\end{align*}

When I enter (2) into [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), the engine says that the equation is a second-order *linear* ordinary differential equation.

Can the substitution be leveraged from here to solve the problem? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think the solution to this ODE has a closed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea that is proposed is to try to find an equation for a function $v$ so that $y'(x)=v(y(x))$. By the chain rule, $y''=v'v$ and thus the equation reads as
$$
vv'=yv+v^2\implies v=0\lor v'=y+v.
$$
The first case gives constant solutions, but contradicts the initicial conditions. In the second case, $v(y)=Ce^y-y-1$. With $v(0)=-1$ one finds $C=0$. For this exceptional case one can now also solve the resulting first order equation
$$
y'(x)=-y(x)-1\implies y(x)=e^{1-x}-1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think Wolfram fails to realize $y$ and $v$ are related. You should end up with the system of equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
v  &= y' &\\
v' &= yv &+ v^2
\end{matrix}
\right\|
$$